# Finding solutions for equations with exponential

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, exponential-function

I have no idea on how to prove that $$ x(e^x-e^{-x})-e^x=0 $$
has at least 2 real solutions in R?
How would you generally go about proving solutions exist if you can't isolate the x or use the quadratic formula?

Comment: How about proving: $f(x) < 0$ and $f(x) \to +\infty$ as $x \to \pm \infty$.

Comment: how does it prove that we have solutions in R

Comment: It is a non-linear equation. Use the bisection method or the Newton method.

Comment: You also need: $f$ is continuous, and the intermediate value theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply through by $e^x$, whihc you can do because $e^x$  is never zero for finite real $x$; so you are looking for solutions to
$$
f(x) = x(e^{2x}-1) - e^{2x} = 0$$

You know that the $f(x)$ is continuous because the product of two continuous functions is continuous, as is the sum of two continuous functions, and $e^{2x}$ is continuous.

You also know that at $x=-30$, 
$$f(-30) = 30(1-e^{-60}) - e^{-60} > 0 $$ since $e^{-60}$ very small compared with  30.  And at $x=0$,
 $$f(0) =  - e^{0} = -1 < 0 $$
So by the intermediate value theorem, $f(x)$ is zero somewhere on the interval $(-30,0)$.

And you also know that at $x=2$
$$
f(2) = 2(e^4-1)-e^4 = e^4 -1 > 0
$$
So by the intermediate value theorem, $f(x)$ is also zero somewhere on the interval $(0,2)$.

The harder problem would be to show there are **only** two real zeros.

Comment: Ah so we use the intermediate value theorem and guess a closed bound where we know that a solution exists, and by doing that 2 times we can say that **at least** two solutions exist in R. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Let's set $f(x)=x(e^x-e^{-x})-e^x$. First, look at $f(0)$:
$$f(0)=0(e^0+e^{-0})-e^0=0-1=-1$$
This means that there are solutions where $f(x)<0$.

Let's take two limits:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}(xe^x-xe^{-x}-e^x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}(x-1)e^x-\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{e^x}=?$$
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to-\infty}(xe^x-xe^{-x}-e^x)=\lim_{x\to-\infty}(x-1)e^x-\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x}{e^x}=?$$
If both of these are greater than $0$, then - given that $f(x)$ is continuous - there are at least two real solutions. Can you tell if this is the case?

Note that this would not guarantee that there are *only* two solutions, merely that at least two solutions must exist.

Comment: doesn't your limit to infinity diverge and wouldn't the -infinity one be undefined?

Comment: @SoHCahToha Yes, the limits are divergent - and you can use L'hopital's rule to calculate them. That means that there must be some points - one on either side of $x=0$ - where $f(x)=0$.

Comment: I don't really get why the fact that these two limit being divergent indicate that there must be some points for which f(x) = 0

Comment: @SoHCahToha Both limits go to *positive* infinity. That means that as $x\to\infty$, $f(x)>0$ for large $x$. This means that $f(x)$ must have gone from negative to positive. Others have already mentioned this through the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem).

Comment: So that tells us that the function must have crosse the x axis at least once, so how could we expand that logic to show that it crosses at least 2 times the x axis?

Comment: @SoHCahToha It crosses once in *each direction*. If we only had one limit, then we could only say that it crosses once. However, we have two.